# Cursor goes to the bottom of the question when editing it

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editor, firefox

I just noticed this on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) now when editing (a) question(s) and [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) (*so far*):

When I click on the "edit" option for a question, that the cursor now goes to the bottom of the question rather than on top.

I also cleared my cache and restarted my browser; same result.

I am using Firefox 51.0.1. Doing a Firefox upgrade to version 51 is what seems to be the issue here. The problem is happening on my Windows 7 machine but not on my Linux Mint machine with the same version of Firefox (51).

From comments:

> *"Just tried this on a UBUNTU VM running on Windows 7. FF50 opened at top of edit box. Upgraded to FF51 and edit box opens with the cursor at the bottom of the text – RiggsFolly"*

and

> *"This also happens in Firefox 52 on windows 7 – Tiny Giant"*

I just tried a few other areas of the network that I am subscribed to and the cursor focuses/stays in the "Title" input as opposed to the textarea of what seems to only be affected at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: No repro, either with the inline editor or when opening it on a new page. What browser are you using?

Comment: @CodyGray Firefox 51.0.1

Comment: Reproduced as well when trying to edit this question with the same Firefox version on Vista...

Comment: well that is most bizarre

Comment: Ahh, yes, it happens when editing this question!

Comment: Now its happening on SO as well

Comment: @RiggsFolly So, this is a recent thing then. It may not have caught up with the others then yet.

Comment: I tried it on FF 50 and it did not happen. Then I did the FF51 upgrade and it started happening

Comment: @RiggsFolly so it's a Firefox related thing which will makes this all that much more harder to figure out why and if it is related to only Firefox and/or Stack.

Comment: @Tunaki Vista?!? :)

Comment: can someone tell me why this got a downvote? I'm obviously not the only person experiencing this.

Comment: Just tried this on a UBUNTU VM running on Windows 7. FF50 opened at top of edit box. Upgraded to FF51 and edit box opens with the cursor at the bottom of the text

Comment: This also happens in FireFox 52 on windows 7

Comment: @TinyGiant I didn't know there was a version 52; so this all seems to have started with 51 and keeps on going then; this one risks in getting very hard to resolve; thanks for that btw.

Comment: [People complain about browsers not following standards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808883/is-there-a-work-around-to-make-rowspan-work-in-ms-browsers), but the one time a browser vendor takes steps to improve their product's standards compliance, things go bananas. This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: @BoltClock True. However, what I don't understand is that on my Linux box using the same version as the one in Windows, it doesn't behave the same and stays on top (Linux) and at the bottom (Windows); that's the thing.

Comment: Same question on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290593/162102

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks Monica. I see I'm not alone in this and the numbers stand to keep growing as time moves on and others upgrade their FF browsers.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, definitely not just you (I didn't know about this MSO question until a few minutes ago).  I've asked [this](http://superuser.com/q/1174680/96202) on Super User to try to find a workaround, but no luck so far.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Sorry Monica, wrong link. This is the one http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342430/1415724

Comment: I can't reproduce this anymore?

Comment: @Braiam Mozilla made an update to a new release (FF 53) and no longer behaves like that anymore. Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: 52.0.2, seems that the change came earlier.

Comment: @Braiam I think you're right; I couldn't remember if the fix happened in v.52 or 53. There must have been too many complaints about it and they modified its behaviour.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Beginning in version 51, Firefox changed the behavior of [`HTMLElement#focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) so that the caret is placed at the end of the text instead of the start of the text. After reviewing the [definition of how focus should behave](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focusing-steps), it does not seem that there is any specification for where the caret should be placed.

The code which causes this in the inline editor is:

```js
$('#wmd-input-342386').focus();
```

The jQuery part is irrelevant, because using the non-jQuery version does the same thing. This is an implementation change introduced by Firefox, and is not due to anything on Stack Overflow's end.

I have included the following MCVE for reference.

```html
<textarea cols="50" rows="10">The caret should be placed at the start of the text, but in Firefox 51+ it is placed at the end of the text instead.</textarea>
<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.focus(); // Give the focus to the frame
    document.querySelector('textarea').focus();
  }, 15);
</script>
```

To reconcile the behavior in all modern browsers (IE9+), you can set the [`selectionEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) property of the element to `0`, which is the equivalent of calling `setSelectionRange(0,0)`.

```html
<textarea cols="50" rows="10">The caret should be placed at the start of the text in all modern browsers now.</textarea>
<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.focus();
    var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
    textarea.focus(); // Give the focus to the frame
    textarea.selectionEnd = 0;
  }, 15);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks again for all you did. I'm sure there are others who are faced with the same problem as I (or will as soon as they upgrade to the newest version). Did you by any chance submit a bug report to Mozilla? I was thinking of doing it earlier, but didn't know quite what to tell them.

Comment: No, I haven't submitted a bug report. I'm allergic to bugzilla.

Comment: *Hahaha!* I get ya. I'll send one and keep you posted, *cheers*

Comment: Sounds good :-)

Comment: I have filed the following bug report on bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1334723

Comment: @RiggsFolly There is more activity in the bug report where someone did post a jsfiddle that behaves the same way https://jsfiddle.net/zevp3dpa/

Answer (score 3):

This behavior was intentionally changed in [bug 1287655 - input/textarea selectionStart, selectionEnd should return cursor position when selection is empty](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1287655)

> ```
> data:text/html,<script>window.onload = function() { var i = document.createElement("input"); i.value="foo"; document.body.appendChild(i); i.focus();  }</script>
> ```
>
> shows where cursor is put. We have it at 0, Chrome puts it at the end of text.

Also see [Firefox Site Compatibility](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/caret-will-be-placed-at-the-end-when-textbox-automatically-gets-focus/):

> Previously, when an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element received a focus
>   with the [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) method, a caret was initially placed at the
>   beginning of the text, and therefore, both the `selectionStart` and
>   `selectionEnd` properties on the form control would always be `0`.
>
> Firefox 51 has changed the behaviour to follow the HTML spec, so that
>   a caret will be placed at the end of the text, and these properties
>   will be the same value as the text length. The
>   [`setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) method can be used to specify the selection
>   range if needed.

Comment: *"This behavior was intentionally changed"* - I take it that Stack didn't foresee that. If Stack doesn't have a fix for that behaviour in some browsers, I take it that I/we will just have to get used to it and live with it. Thanks for this btw. Am wondering if the "feature request" tag should be added to the question at this point?

Comment: @Fred-ii- You can ask a feature request about using `setSelectionRange(0,0)` to move the cursor to the beginning. But Chrome users might be used to have the cursor at the end, and oppose the change.

Comment: *"But Chrome users might be used to have the cursor at the end, and oppose the change"* - I don't quite understand what you meant by that, but the way I look at it is: when editing in any browser, one would think that it would only make sense to have the cursor be at the upper left should the beginning of what stands to be a long question, that code and/or text needs to be edited at the top, rather than the pointer be at the bottom and then having to go all the way back up to edit those parts, if you know what I mean ;-)

Comment: Here's a related bug report btw https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1287655 which seems to also explain everything. I had a feeling about that actually, about if a textarea was "empty". Funny how my instinct works at times.

Comment: *"You can ask a feature request about using `setSelectionRange(0,0)` to move the cursor to the beginning"* - I take it that I should be asking another question and add a reference link to this question? Or, should I edit my question?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I would ask a new question tagged [feature-request], and explain why you think it's better to move the cursor to the beginning

Comment: I posted a new question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342417/1415724

Comment: ...to which I received 2 negative votes; lovely. ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- Probably they are from Chrome users who don't want to change

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. Personally, I'm no fan of Chrome. It messes with my OS which I don't particularly appreciate.

Comment: @Fred does your issue with Google Chrome extend to Chromium based browsers? I'm one of the six users of Vivaldi, and I love it.

Comment: @TinyGiant My issue isn't with Google Chrome; I don't have it installed, I only have FF (and IE 11). Also FF 51 on Linux, unless I didn't grasp your comment.

Comment: @Fred I was replying to *"Personally, I'm no fan of Chrome. It messes with my OS which I don't particularly appreciate."*

Comment: @Oriol I don't really understand how they got from *"selectionStart and selectionEnd must return the offset (in logical order) to the character that immediately follows the text entry cursor"* to *"the HTML spec says that the cursor must be inserted at the end of the text"*. That makes very little sense. I realize this has nothing to do with you, but I don't like commenting on bugzilla.

Comment: @TinyGiant Only six Vivaldi users? Wikipedia says 1 million. And I am also a bit lost about which part of the spec made they think the cursor must be at the end, but they seem convinced

Comment: @Oriol it's a running joke that Vivaldi is a wonderful browser, with a relatively tiny user base. As for their line of thought, it is unclear. There is zero real discussion just "This is the problem, this is what we're doing, here's the commit"

Comment: For what it's worth, Chrome only does set the focus to the end of text on `<input>` element, not on textarea, so chrome SO users wouldn't be affected by an `setSelectionRange(0)` fix.

Comment: @Oriol Chrome puts the caret at the beginning of SE posts, at least for now.  I use both Chrome and Firefox and they are inconsistent now (as of Firefox 51).