# Have the cursor placed/stay at the upper top left in edit mode

Tags: feature-request, editor

As per an earlier question of mine ([Cursor goes to the bottom of the question when editing it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342386/cursor-goes-to-the-bottom-of-the-question-when-editing-it)), the cursor in Firefox 51+ now goes to the bottom of a post when entering "edit" mode.

One would think that it would make sense to have the cursor stay at the top left, where code and/or text need to be edited at the beginning of the post, rather than  at the end of the content and then having to go all the way back up.

This new behaviour has been recognized and seems to be the "new behaviour", per the following Bugzilla report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1287655

[A comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342386/cursor-goes-to-the-bottom-of-the-question-when-editing-it#comment438298_342416) on my other question suggested using `setSelectionRange(0,0)`.

Comment: I guess people are disagreeing this needs to be implemented? See [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259917).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure.... well that was "before" this new behaviour. What am I not grasping here?? or you guys

Comment: I don't know, I can't read peoples minds, Fred. This is tagged 'feature request', so the most common reason for votes is agreement or disagreement.

Comment: If you want to edit the *end* of the post, this new behaviour is a big win!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Up until it happens to them or they feel that they can live with it. Yeah, you're right; we can't read peoples' minds and that's just it. One would think that they'd share their views.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm curious; why do you feel that it would be *"a big win"*?

Comment: For the same reason you think it's better to have the cursor be at the top if you want to edit the start of the post - it's already where you want it to be.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess this would be a personal preference then. For years, the cursor was located at the top left, and then all of a sudden it goes to the bottom. I guess you're used to sudden changes. Sort of like when you've been eating Corn Flakes with a big of sugar all your life, then all of a sudden having to eat lemons with salt. That's the analogy I'm trying to convey here.

Comment: To continue your analogy, you want to get the familiar corn flakes back for yourself but make some other users (those whose browsers already put the caret at the end) eat the surprising lemons as a result. It's not, in my view at least, up to SO to override browser behaviour.

Comment: I've just decided that I was correct to abandon firefox.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah I guess so. So Firefox/Mozilla "decided for us" as to what's supposed to be "good for us", just like Corn Flakes; with or without sugar or just get the Frosted Flakes and scrape the sugar coating off ;-) Point taken.

Comment: I guess it's just a matter of years before more and more people start to be annoyed at the editor's behaviour in FF.

Comment: @Fred given that you don't actually have to scroll to the top of the text, you *can* use the home key. That doesn't change the fact that Firefox changed the accepted behavior of a common function under the guise of adhering to a specification which says nothing about where the cursor should be inserted. This is one of those things where everyone followed a convention for so long that no specification was needed for it. Just like it is not up to Stack Overflow to change the expected behavior of the browser, it is not up to the browser to change the expected behavior of the web.

Comment: Firefox dev [are saying this is according to spec](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1334723#c8) so.... I guess everyone is used to not following the standard.

Comment: @Tunaki but they are pointing at a different spec. The spec they are pointing at says that `selectionEnd` and `selectionStart` should return the position of the cursor if no text is selected, as previously it would always be 0 regardless of where the cursor was. There is no spec that states where the cursor should be placed on focus. So they fixed the fact that no position was returned previously, but also implemented a needless change to the convention of where the cursor should be placed.

Comment: @TinyGiant *"you can use the home key"* - Yes, that I did use. - *"Just like it is not up to Stack Overflow to change the expected behavior of the browser"* - They're under no obligation to do it, I can appreciate that. It was just the fact that as of the FF 51 upgrade, that things changed. I guess nobody saw that one coming; I sure didn't.

Comment: What I find funny is that the bug report claims Chrome already put the caret at the end of the block. I must not be using Chrome then.

Comment: Chrome does not currently put the caret at the end of SE post bodies.  I use both Chrome and Firefox and I am now experiencing inconsistent behavior when editing.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I can't account for (Google) Chrome since I don't use it and for a specific reason (too broad to discuss).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Maybe you can post a comment about (Google) Chrome under Tiny Giant's answer, see if he'll do up a new script but that's up to that person to decide.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry if I was unclear.  Chrome currently behaves the way Firefox used to; there's nothing to change there.  This issue exists only in Firefox (51+).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) to fix this problem in Firefox.

This will create a proxy for all calls to `HTMLElement#focus`. The proxy function calls the native function then—if the focused element has the class `wmd-input`, and there is no selection range—moves the caret to the start of the text. The `wmd-input` class check restricts the effects of the script to the editor textarea only. The "no selection range" check is to avoid collision with the code formatting function of the editor which itself calls the focus method.

[Github](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/blob/master/FirefoxFocusFix.user.js) / [Install](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/raw/master/FirefoxFocusFix.user.js)

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Firefox Focus Fix
// @namespace    http://tinygiant.io
// @version      1.0.0.2
// @description  Fixes the recent change implemented by Firefox which places the caret at the end of the text on focus instead of the beginning
// @author       @TinyGiant
// @include      /^https?:\/\/(.*\.)?(stackexchange.com|stackoverflow.com|serverfault.com|superuser.com|askubuntu.com|stackapps.com|mathoverflow.net)/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).textContent = `(function() {
    const oldfocus = HTMLElement.prototype.focus;

    HTMLElement.prototype.focus = function() {
        oldfocus.call(this);
        if (/wmd-input/.test(this.className))
            if (this.selectionEnd === this.selectionStart)
                this.selectionEnd = 0;
    };
})()`;
```

Comment: Sounds promising. I take that I'll have to run this from GreaseMonkey or similar? I.e.: usi (User|Unified Script Injector) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/userunified-script-injector/ Edit: wait, that's for Android.

Comment: Yeah, greasemonkey on firefox, see the first link in my answer for instructions.

Comment: Nice!! Hey, thanks for this, it works beautifully. I'm sure others who have the same problem as I will benefit from this, *cheers*. Btw, you're quite the JS guru and troubleshooter ;-)

Comment: I'm definitely not overly knowledgeable on the subject, but I know enough to get by and I learn more every day. Thanks for the compliment though.

Comment: You and I both. Continuing to learn makes for "never a dull moment"; and you're welcome.

Comment: I just noticed something really strange as I was trying to edit tags in a question. When I started typing the intended word "parse", starting from "p" ... "a", soon as I started typing the letter "a", the cursor would move over to the left of the letter "p" *lol*. I thought this was another (new) bug at first, but then I asked myself: *"I think this has to do with the script Tiny Giant wrote"*; I was right. Just thought I'd let you know about it and for others who may be using your script. The solution for now would be for me to disable the script when editing tags.

Comment: @Fred-ii- fixed, click the install link again to update the script.

Comment: That worked beautifully, thanks again.

Comment: Could you please add meta to the URL regex?

Comment: @Monica What brower and page is it not working on? The `\w*.?` should match meta.

Comment: @TinyGiant it's not working for me on [this post on Worldbuilding meta](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4037/28), in Firefox 51.0.1 on Windows.  It does work for [this post on Worldbuilding main](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/51388/28).  Both are my posts and using the inline editor.

Comment: @Monica fixed, it was only allowing one subdomain.

Comment: @TinyGiant thanks -- verified!